# setState Does Not Define State Variable (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am a noob of ReactJS and I created a Homepage for Users to view after logging in or registering . I am getting the data from my custom API(NodeJS) but once I fetch the data and attempt to setState it appears that it is not updating the state variables.

Here is my code.

```
export class SideMenu extends Component {

constructor(props) {

        super(props)

        this.state = {
            user: {},

        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
        console.log(this.user);
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/returningusers").then((response) => {
            const data = response.data.User[0]
            console.log(data)

            this.setState({
                user: data
            })
        })
    }
```

I really need help with this, it has slowed down my momentum and I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: If you change `console.log(this.user)` in `componentDidMount()` to `console.log(this.state.user)`, does it log the data?

Comment: I tried that and it is still null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that's the correct syntax for an ES6 class method. How about trying the below instead of the arrow function:

```
fetchData() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/returningusers").then((response) => {
            const data = response.data.User[0]
            console.log(data)

            this.setState({
                user: data
            })
        })
    }
```

Also you need to return Promises and either `await` or `then` them. For example:

```
async componentDidMount() {
        await this.fetchData(); // you need to wait until this finishes
        console.log(this.state.user);
    }
    // and you need to return the Promise here
    fetchData() => {
        return axios.get("http://localhost:3001/returningusers").then((response) => {
            const data = response.data.User[0]
            console.log(data)

            this.setState({
                user: data
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: I think I see the issue! I've updated my answer. You were calling a function that then invokes a Promise function. You weren't returning or awaiting anything. Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Still no dice. Also I appreciate your help so far man, thanks a lot.

Comment: Noticed something else this morning. When you set state, those values will be on `this.state`. So that `user` var in your `console.log` should be `this.state.user`.

Comment: And perhaps do your `console.log` check in your  `render` function. I'm guessing that's where you'll probably using this value.

Comment: Still not working and only returning null/undefined. This is starting to get really frustrating.